# Allow only edit response in a Google form

Tags: google-forms, google-font-api

I have a Google form connect to a Google sheet that stores all the data from the responders of the Google form.

This Google form is officially closed(past deadline) but I need to add a new field in this Google form and make responders who have already response to my form to fill the new field.

**Allow the previous responders to edit there response** and no others can fill this Google form(others will see form closed message).

Comment: This isn't a programming question.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  Google may direct people here for support, but Stack Overflow isn't for getting support on general usage.  Go to the product forum:  [Link to Product Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/docs)

Comment: Then why is there a google-form tag here in overflow?

Comment: The Apps Script programming language can be used with Google Forms.  Apps Script is the programming language, and it can be used with many Google products.  Here is a link to what topics are "on topic": [Link to On Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: That's what I'm asking Sandy. Can we do this with Google app script?

Comment: In the General Settings, there is a checkbox for "Edit after submit".  Is that checked?  In the lower right hand corner of the "New" Google Forms, there is a question mark.  Click that, and then click on "Help Center."  You can create an Edit URL with Apps Script, but depending on the situation, that might be more work than necessary, and not be worth it.  [Link to Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getediturl)